# How to have a self reference in NoSQL database

Tags: firebase, nosql, google-cloud-firestore

I am planning on creating an app that uses Cloud Firestore's realtime database. However, I really only have experience with mysql relational databases. How could I have this sort of structure in a nosql database:

```
user (collection)
    firstName: String
    lastName:  String
    username:  String
    email:     String
    password:  String
    birthdate: Date
    accountCreationDate: Date
    phoneNumber: String
    friends: [user]
```

As I pointed out, `user` would be a collection and each document in `user`s would have the fields I listed. This is pretty straight forward but what about the friends "field"? Each user can have an array or set of friends (each of which is a user themselves). How do I have this sort of self relationship in a nosql database? Thank you!

Comment: each document can have subcollections. Perhaps in your case its better to have nested data in documents.
For this [Check here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/structure-data)

Comment: design you database based on your view , that how firebase suggest to design you database

Comment: A NoSQL structure would be similar to that where the user would possibly be a user id and then the child nodes would be firstName, lastName etc. Have you gone through the [Getting Started](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/) guides or referenced the multitude of NoSQL [tutorials](https://gonehybrid.com/firebase-database-best-practices/) on the internet?

Comment: The modeling of data in relational databases is pretty consistent, since they all speak SQL and we've defined data modeling in terms that work across all of them. NoSQL databases don't have a common model or query language. So there is no single way to model things across NoSQL databases. That said: I'd consider using `Reference` for storing the references to friends. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/data-types